# Eventbrite OAuth authorize Site for Mobile

Tags: android, ios, oauth, eventbrite

My iOS and Android apps offer the possibility to attach Eventbrite to a user's profile.
However, the authorization page at "https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/authorize",
is not well formatted for mobile, with things like the login and password text fields stretching wider than the view itself.

Is there a more mobile friendly login page for Evenbrite's OAuth apis?
Or perhaps am I missing a parameter to https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/authorize to make it look better on mobile?

Comment: Note, I work at Eventbrite.  The fact that the login page isn't optimized for mobile is a bug and is being treated as such.  There is nothing that you're missing in your implementation or request.  Once this is resolved I'll update this question/answer.

Comment: Thanks brianz, I look forward to your reply :D

Answer (score 0):

I sent a mail to Eventbrite today to ask about the same thing, here is the answer :

> Hi Ivan!
>
> Thanks for contacting us! Mobilizing the login page is on the short
>   list for upcoming features.
>
> Unfortunately, we don't have an exact timeline yet -- but stay tuned
>   by subscribing to our newsletter and we'll let you know:
>   http://eepurl.com/buGfH
>
> Cheers! Mitch